# Combinations of triangles that form a convex hull

Tags: matlab, geometry, delaunay, set-union

I have a set of triangles. I am looking for a way to **find all combinations of these triangles that constitute a convex hull when joined together**. The convex hull should be empty, ie. no points inside the convex hull only on the edge. And only triangles that share a side can be joined together, ie. no gaps in the union.

**Example:** The following points gives 12 triangles (Delaunay Triangulation).

```
xy = [3.3735 0.7889; -0.1072 -3.4814; -3.9732 4.1955; -5 5; 5 5; 5 -5; -5 -5];
DT = delaunayTriangulation(xy);
triplot(DT);
%The coordinates for each triangle -- each row is a triangle.
TRIX = reshape(DT.Points(DT.ConnectivityList, 1), size(DT.ConnectivityList));
TRIY = reshape(DT.Points(DT.ConnectivityList, 2), size(DT.ConnectivityList));
```

[image: 12 triangles]

I am looking for the largest convex hulls, so the convex hull should include as many triangles as possible. But if I have all the possible combinations I can easily filter out those with less triangles. In the example from above I should end up with these six convex hulls:

[image: 6 convex hulls]

I am guessing that I should use that every triangle has at most three neighbouring triangles (one for each side). And that I should check whether the sum of the angle is less or equal 180 degrees at the points of intersect. This would insure that the union is convex -- see figure below. (The angle might also be exactly 360 degrees if several triangles form a full circle).

[image: 5 convex hulls]

---

Triangle angles:

```
% Vectors connecting points
diffx = diff([TRIX TRIX(:,1)], [], 2); diffy = diff([TRIY TRIY(:,1)], [], 2); diffxy = [diffx(:) diffy(:)];
% Norm
normxy = reshape( arrayfun(@(row) norm(diffxy(row,:)), 1:size(diffxy,1)), size(DT.ConnectivityList));
nominator = repmat(sum(normxy.^2, 2), 1, 3) - 2*normxy.^2;
denominator = 2 * repmat(prod(normxy, 2), 1, 3)./normxy;
% Angle
tri_angle = acosd(nominator./denominator);
tri_angle = circshift(tri_angle, [0 -1]); % Shift so the angles match the correct point.
```

I reformat the information such that rows are points and columns are triangles:

```
n_tri = size(TRIX,1); % Number of triangles
% Adjacency matrix connecting points (rows) with triangles (columns).
adj_points = zeros(size(xy,1), n_tri);
adj_angle = NaN(size(adj_points));
for point =1:size(xy,1)
    idx = find(DT.ConnectivityList == point);
    [a_tri, ~] = ind2sub(size(DT.ConnectivityList), idx);
    adj_points(point,a_tri) = 1;
    adj_angle(point,a_tri) = tri_angle(idx);
end
```

I loop through all the edges and calculate the angles on both sides of the edge (`edges angles`). This way I am able to find pairs of triangles that form a convex set (`adj_convex`):

```
DT_edges = edges(DT); % All edges in the Delaunay triangulation
% Adjacency matrix connecting edges (rows) with triangles (columns).
adj_edge = logical(adj_points(DT_edges(:,1),:) .* adj_points(DT_edges(:,2),:));

edgesangles = NaN(size(DT_edges));
adj = zeros(n_tri); % Adjacency matrix indicating which triangles are neighbours.
adj_convex = zeros(n_tri);
for edge=1:size(DT_edges,1)
    % The angles on either side of the edge.
    tri = adj_edge(edge,:);
    t = adj_angle(DT_edges(edge,:), tri );
    edgesangles(edge,:) = sum(t, 2);
    tri_idx = find(tri);
    adj(tri_idx,tri_idx) = 1;
    adj_convex(tri_idx,tri_idx) = prod(edgesangles(edge,:) <= 180);
end
convexedges = (edgesangles <= 180);
% Set diagonals to zero.
adj(logical(eye(n_tri))) = 0;
adj_convex(logical(eye(n_tri))) = 0;
```

However I am unsure how to proceed if I want all combinations, or the largest convex hull. And I am unsure how to account for the special case where several triangles from a full circle (ie. 360 degrees).

Comment: Would solutions which don't use delauny triangles but arbitrary triangles instead be valid as well? I see possible solutions for both, but both problems are very different.

Comment: From your description I see more than the 6 solutions you found. Maybe you can label the points / triangles so we can talk about the solutions.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. How can several triangles form a full circle?

Comment: I don't get the question. From the definition of a convex hull (wikipedia): *the convex hull or convex envelope of a set X of points in the Euclidean plane or Euclidean space is the smallest convex set that contains X*. Now, why do you want a convex hull of a subset, when the convex hull of all points is by definition always the largest? You can rearrange the delauney triangulation in different ways, if that's of interest. Also, I do not think that "all combinations" is a good answer (or feasible). Consider e.g. dynamic programming or other algos, their strength is reducing the combinations.

Comment: @Daniel. I've added a label to each of the 12 triangles. The largest convex sets made up of triangles {4,1}, {5}, {8}, {2,3}, {6,7}, and {1,6,3}. I am not sure what you mean by arbitrary triangles. I am not looking for a solution where triangles overlap, or don't intersect at all. Full circle example: http://amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/B5/B5g6.png

Comment: @Oleg Given the 6 points I am trying to find the optimal 7th position. I am not sure my approach will work, but Dehne, Klein and Seidel (2002) have shown that there exists a local maximum when neighbouring points from a convex set. That is why I am interested in the subset. Good point on "all combinations".

Comment: @bonna you are using a specific triangulation, choosing the triangles different might result in a bigger convex hull

Answer (score 2):

This answer can be solved with a simple recursive algorithm:

1. Start with any triangle
2. Find all triangles that share an edge with this triangle
3. For each of these triangles, check if this set is convex.

   - Stop if not convex
   - Add triangle connected to last added triangle to set that still needs to be tested

So this algorithm is recursive, as it greedily tries to add more triangles to the set until it is not convex any more. The code below gives this result (I omitted all trivial (1 triangle) answers.

The check if there are no interior points in the convex hull is a bit naive: construct convex hull and see if all points are on it.

[image]

```
function [convexTriangleSets,DT] = triangles()
    % inputs
    xy = [3.3735 0.7889; -0.1072 -3.4814; -3.9732 4.1955; -5 5; 5 5; 5 -5; -5 -5];
    DT = delaunayTriangulation(xy);

    function convexTriangleSets = testAddTriangle(iTriangle,attachedTriangleIndices,includedTriangleIndices)
        % add triangle
        includedTriangleIndices(end+1) = iTriangle;

        % naive test if allpoint of set of triangles are on convex hull
        nodes = unique(DT(includedTriangleIndices,:));
        coords = DT.Points(nodes,:);
        ch = convexHull(delaunayTriangulation(coords)); 
        allNodesOnConvexHull = length(nodes) == length(ch)-1;

        if ~allNodesOnConvexHull
            convexTriangleSets = {};
            return 
        end

        % find triangles connected to iTriangle
        currentTriangle = DT.ConnectivityList(iTriangle,:)';

        attachedCell = DT.edgeAttachments(currentTriangle([1 2 3]),currentTriangle([2 3 1]));
        attachedRow = unique([attachedTriangleIndices,attachedCell{:}]);
        attachedTriangleIndices = attachedRow(~ismember(attachedRow,includedTriangleIndices));

        % recursively try to expand connected triangles
        convexTriangleSets = {sort(includedTriangleIndices)};
        for ii = 1:length(attachedTriangleIndices)
            convexTriangleSets = [convexTriangleSets,...
                testAddTriangle(attachedTriangleIndices(ii),...
                                attachedTriangleIndices,...
                                includedTriangleIndices)]; %#ok<AGROW>
        end
    end

    includedTriangleIndices = [];
    attachedTriangleIndices = [];
    convexTriangleSets = {};
    for iTriangle = 1:DT.size
        convexTriangleSets = [convexTriangleSets,...
            testAddTriangle(iTriangle,attachedTriangleIndices,includedTriangleIndices)]; %#ok<AGROW>
    end

    % filter single triangles
    convexTriangleSets(cellfun(@length,convexTriangleSets) == 1) = [];

    % filter unique sets; convert to string because matlab cannot unique a cell array
    [~,c] = unique(cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%d,',x),convexTriangleSets,'UniformOutput',false));

    convexTriangleSets = convexTriangleSets(c);

    % plot result
    n = ceil(sqrt(length(convexTriangleSets)));
    for kk = 1:length(convexTriangleSets)
        subplot(n,n,kk)
        triplot(DT,'k')
        hold on
        patch('faces',DT(convexTriangleSets{kk},:), 'vertices', DT.Points, 'FaceColor','r');
    end
end
```

Comment: How does this find the diamond + chevron in the example? you can find the diamond, but as the chevrn  is composed of two triangles it will never be added

Comment: The chevron is not a convex hull, the question is to find all triangles that constitute a convex hull when joined together

Comment: Thanks. I ended up removing your 'single triangle' filtering, and added the follow code (http://pastebin.com/Eynbvxz5) after the 'unique sets' filtering and before the plot. So it only returns the largest convex set.

Comment: What do you mean by the largest set, the most triangles or the largest covered area?

Comment: @ThijsD the 4 triangles that are the chevron+diamond are convex.

Comment: @vish, that combination conflicts with the second part of the question: The convex hull should be empty, ie. no points inside the convex hull only on the edge.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully some of your concerns can be answered using this lines of code

**Convexity of polygon**

Assume you have a set of triangles, then you should remove all points inside that polygon, i.e. do only look at points at the border of the polygon. You can check whether or not a point is inside the polygon using the [inpolygon](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) function

```
[in,on] = inpolygon(xq,yq,xv,yv);
```

The condition, that all angles need to be less that 180° is in this case i assume sufficient. You could also just create a convex hull, and check whether or not the set is identical. Use [convhull](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html)

```
K = convhull(X,Y)
```

**Is subset of larger one?**

One question you addressed is, how you do check if one (convex) polygon is a subset of another (convex) polygon. Let's assume the following; you have a target polygon and you know all triangles in that polygon. Next you also know all other (convex) polygons containing at least one of those polygons. Then, you can check if one polygon is a subset of another by using again `inpolygon`

```
x %// target polygon x
y
xt %// test polygon x
yt
in = inpolygon(x, v, xt, yt);
if sum(in)==length(x)
   %// target polygon is subset of testpolygon
end
```

**The *find all* condition**

Here I would use the - say - *poor mans approach*. Simply brute-force loop through all combinations and check for convexity. 
A list of all triangles is given to you by the DelaunayTriangulation. I.e.

```
DT(:,:)
```

gives you all triangles and its points.

**The delaunayTriangulation class**

You are already using the delaunayTriangulation class, why not use methods of that class? You have basically all you need

1. [Check if triangulation is subset of other triangulation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.isinterior.html)
2. [Get boundary points of triangulation.](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.freeboundary.html)
3. [Get the convex hull of a triangulation.](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.convexhull.html)

Do you need more?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but none of these methods seems particularly efficient. Creating a `convhull` and checking whether the set is identical, seems fare more computationally expensive than calculating and summing angles. Similarly using `inpolygon` to compare subsets seems quite wasteful when I can just look at the number of triangles in the convex hull. The convex set with triangles {1,6,3} is larger than {1,6}.